# no results when applying flink tumble window in flink table api

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-flink, sink, flink-table-api

I have the same problem when I study https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/zh/docs/try-flink/table_api/. When I use tumble window, I got nothing in MySQL sink.

```
return transactions
            .window(Tumble.over(lit(1).hour()).on($("transaction_time")).as("log_ts"))
            .groupBy($("account_id"), $("log_ts"))
            .select(
                    $("account_id"),
                    $("log_ts").start().as("log_ts"),
                    $("amount").sum().as("amount"));
```

When I use the default 8 parallelism, I found some subtask didn't receive records from upstream in the web front-end.
[image]

But when I add `tEnv.getConfig().addConfiguration(new Configuration().set(CoreOptions.DEFAULT_PARALLELISM, 1));` in the main function, I got results in the MySQL sink, and the web front-end was like below:
[image]

Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: What's your source? It looks like some source partitions don't receive data and thus the watermark will not advance.

Comment: You are right, thanks.